# The input values ​are empty after the refresh - how to resolve that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an api that is of the `GET` type and I receive the data below code and store it in `fetchPlants`

```
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPlants = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
          "URL",
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          }
        );
        setAllPlants(data.plantsList);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
      }
    };

    fetchPlants();
  }, []);
```

And I have an api of `POST` type that I send with the below code and I put loading inside it
When it is sent successfully, the page is directed and I have no problem, but I get an error when `setLoading` is set to `false` and refresh page, the input values ​​are empty and the user has to enter the input values ​​again.

```
  const sendDisease = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const api = "URL";

      const { data } = await axios.post(api, formData, {
        headers: {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });
      if (data) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        navigate("/dashboard/diseases/");
        toast.success(data.success, { autoClose: 15000 });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      console.log(e);
      toast.error(e.response.data.error, { autoClose: 15000 });
      console.log(e.response.data.error);
    }
  };
```

this is my form:

```
            <div className="form-row mt-4">
              <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label className="font-weight-bold" for="">
                  Unique Name
                </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="unique_name"
                  placeholder="Unique Name"
                  required
                  onChange={(e) => setUniqueName(e.target.value)}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label className="font-weight-bold" for="">
                  Title
                </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="title"
                  placeholder="Title"
                  onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                  required
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-primary mt-4"
              onClick={sendDisease}
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
```

I want the values ​​not to be clear, but when it goes false, the input values ​​are empty. how to resolve that?

Comment: All of your form inputs are missing the `value` field so the transient DOM state that holds that value is destroyed when the inputs are unmounted. Please go through https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: i should define empty `useState` and define value to each input?

Comment: Yep thats it, one for each field